# How to Add a link to Bootstrap Select Options

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, href

Hi I'm trying to add a link to a Bootstrap Select Option.  How I do that

This is my code

```
<select class="visible-phone span3 select-margintop">
    <option>Servicios</option>
    <option><a href="link . com">Test 1</a></option>
    <option><a href="link . com">Test 2</a></option>
    <option><a href="link . com">Test 3</a></option>
</select>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Should work:

```
<select onchange="location = this.value;">
 <option value="home.html">home</option>
 <option value="team.html">team</option>
 <option value="contact.html">contact</option>
</select>
```

Comment: For a more simple solution `onchange="location = this.value;"` would work aswell.

Answer (score 1):

You can't make a link inside a `select` element. However, you can use `value` to redirect a user when it is selected.

```
<select class="visible-phone span3 select-margintop">
    <option>Servicios</option>
    <option value="link.com">Link 1</option>
</select>
```

Comment: You should fix the `</a>` tag inside the option.

Comment: :P Must have missed it

Answer (score 1):

Not the most semantical solution, but you can also try this:

```
<select>
    <option onClick="window.location = 'http://www.foo.bar'" >Foo</option>
    <option onClick="window.location = 'http://www.foo.bar'">Bar</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps something like this?

```
<select name="forma" onchange="location = this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;">
 <option value="Home.php">Home</option>
 <option value="Contact.php">Contact</option>
 <option value="Sitemap.php">Sitemap</option>
</select>
```